# The module of gradient of distance function on Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

As Yau said in Lectures on Differential geometry, It is also important to note that the distance function $\rho(x)\equiv d(x,p)$ is smooth on $M\backslash\rm{Cut}(p)$ and it satisfies
$$
|\nabla\rho|^2=\Sigma g^{ij}\rho_i\rho_j=1\ \rm{on}\ M\backslash\rm{Cut}(p),
$$
where$(g^{ij})=(g_{ij})^{-1}$ and $(g_{ij})$ is the matrix of the Riemannian metric in the maximal normal coordinate chart.

My problem is how to obtain $|\nabla\rho|^2=1$ where Yau didn't give a proof. I think it might be related to that geodesic is normal.

Comment: Note that $\nabla\rho$ is the tangent vector to the unit speed geodesics passing through $p$

Comment: Also, the equality is not valid on $M\setminus Cut(p)$ but on $M\setminus (Cut(p)\cup\{p\})$, since $\rho$ is not differentiable at $p$.

Answer (score 3):

It suffices to show that for each $q \in M\backslash(\operatorname{Cut}(p) \cup \{p\})$ and unit vector $v \in T_q$, the directional derivative satisfies $v\cdot\nabla\rho \le 1$.

Let $c: (-\delta,\delta) \rightarrow M$ be a geodesic such that $\gamma(0) = q$, $\gamma'(0) = v$, and $d(q,\gamma(t)) = t$. Then by the definition of a directional derivative and the triangle inequality,
\begin{align*}
v\cdot\nabla\rho(q) &= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{\rho(\gamma(t)) - \rho(\gamma_0)}{t}\\
&= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{d(p,\gamma(t))-d(p,q)}{t}\\
&\le \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{d(q,\gamma(t)}{t}\\
&= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{t}{t}\\
&= 1.
\end{align*}